# "Unexpected Failure" compiling with Xcode and code generated with CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I've been using [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) very successfully for a number of years. My applications are almost all Objective-C but sometimes I include Swift.

Just recently, with the upgrade to macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, almost all my Xcode 15.1 builds are getting an error:

> Unexpected Failure

I tracked this down to a file, when Swift is included, that is generated from CocaPods with a name like:

```
./Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-APPLICATION/Pods-APPLICATION-resources.sh
```

This is the shell script segment that is generating the error:

```bash
function on_error {
  echo "$(realpath -mq "${0}"):$1: error: Unexpected failure"
}
trap 'on_error $LINENO' ERR
```

The **Unexpected failure** is occurring in this portion of the script - but in this case because `realpath -mq` is a wrong way of using `realpath` - as the `-mq` is an invalid option. This might be a macOS change.

But it really just masks the reason that `on_error` was called.

All of my applications that were working are getting this same error, and this is without making any changes.

Has anyone else encountered this recent problem? I'm stuck.